# If input is checked, addclass active to fieldset with class that's equal to the input's id

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I know something about jQuery, but this goes above my knowledge. Hope you can help me out.

The title says it all;

- if input with id='hot' is :checked
- then addClass('active') to fieldset with class='hot'
- if input is deselected (already know how to do that) then removeClass('active')

My HTML:

```
<fieldset>

  <div class="item">
    <input name="drinks" id="hot" type="radio">
    <label for="hot">Hot</label>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <input name="drinks" id="cold" type="radio">
    <label for="cold">Cold</label>
  </div>

  <fieldset class="hot">

    <div class="item">
      <input name="hot" id="coffee" type="radio">
      <label for="coffee">Coffee</label>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <input name="hot" id="tea" type="radio">
      <label for="tea">Tea</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</fieldset>
```

My CSS:

```
fieldset > fieldset{
  display:none;
}

fieldset > fieldset.active{
  display:block;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dbgGm)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on context page (coffee, tea???)

Comment: will change the id's of the divs, if i need them at all

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("#hot").change(function() {
    $("." + this.id).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Was more thinking about leaving 'hot' out of jquery so I can use it multiple times on one page with different id's.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is bigger than you are thinking, so:

```
$("input[type=radio]").bind('change.active',function(){
  $(".active").removeClass('active');
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("."+this.id).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

As the element with the `id='hot'` is a radio you need to be careful to remove the active elements when you change the other radios.

Hope it helped

Comment: Hmm yeah got a problem now with selecting other radio's.. When I select other radios in a bigger list, the active class is removed, instead i want the active class only removed when the radio button it links to is deselected.. can't get it to work, you?

Comment: In this demo you can see my problem, if i select hot, the list comes down, but if i select green, the list goes up again. Instead I want it to stay active.. possible? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CJLCG/4/)

Comment: change the `$("input[type=radio]")` for `$("input[type=radio][name=drinks]")` but you'll still have problems if you want to have more than one active filedset at the same time, you should also add a type identifier to the fieldset, otherwise you can get stuck in loops.
see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CJLCG/5/) for a beater solution

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm in a good mood:

```
$("input[name='drinks']").change( function() {
    $("fieldset").children("fieldset").removeClass("active");
    var elem = "fieldset." + this.id;
    $( elem ).addClass( "active" );
});
```

Also, check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/CJLCG/).

Comment: Use `this.id` -- It's faster.

Comment: careful, `$("fieldset>fieldset")` is not supported in all jQuery versions, you should use `$("fieldset").children("fieldset")`

Comment: Thanks for the comments tymeJV and Paraíso, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your html is invalid. Using the same value across different ids is considered invalid.
2. I changed your markup and added the usage of data attributes ([Read More](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/))

Javascript:

```
lastElement = null

$("fieldset:eq( 0 ) > div input[type=radio]").on( "click", function() {
    // Assign $(this) to a var for a cleaner feel
    var t = $(this) 

    // Assign a var with the "data-id" value of the clicked input.
    var x = $(this).data("id");

    // Find a fieldset with a class named with whatever "x" var holds
    var y = $("fieldset\." + x);

    // If the lastElement is not null and is different from "t" ( $(this) ) 
    // Remove class active from the last fieldset. 
    if (typeof lastElement !== null && lastElement !== t) { $("fieldset\."+$(lastElement).data("id")).removeClass("active") } 

    if (t.is(':checked')) {
        // Assign lastElement to 't'
        lastElement = t

        $(y).addClass("active")
      }
});
```

Markup:

```
<fieldset>

  <div class="item" id="drinks">
    <input name="drinks" data-id="hot" type="radio">
    <label for="hot">Hot</label>
  </div>

  <div class="item" id="drinks">
    <input name="drinks" data-id="cold" type="radio">
    <label for="cold">Cold</label>
  </div>

  <fieldset class="hot">

    <div class="item" id="coffee">
      <input name="hot" id="coffee" type="radio">
      <label for="coffee">Coffee</label>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="tea">
      <input name="hot" id="tea" type="radio">
      <label for="tea">Tea</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</fieldset>
```

Here is a working fiddle of what I believe is the desired behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/TG65v/1/

(explanations of the logic is included in the JS snippet)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, my real file is more complicated, and the 'this' is not working because I hide this and work with an image in the label tag. Also my code is longer, and want to add it to more fieldsets. Sorry for not being very clear with my question. Code below is working for me, simply have to multiply and change it a few times.

```
$("input[name='drinks']").click(function(){
    $('fieldset.hot_drinks').addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks for your answers!